# Menu navigation bar change highlighted color and stay while user visiting the same page

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color, menuitem

On my website I tried to give more style to the navigation bar, when a menu item has been hovered over the background color changes, what I am trying to do is when it has been clicked on/selected I want the background color to stay until another menu item has been clicked/selected.

I have already tried several examples of similar queries on this website but I can only get it partially working. It only works when the `href="#"` but when I replace this with `href="homepage.html"` the background color of the menu item will not stay and will change back.

As a single page it works fine however when I create  pages for each item it no longer works.

```
    <style type="text/css">

#navigation a:hover  {background:#5B000C; color:#ffffff;} 
#navigation{ float:left; background-color:#000099; width:600px; height:25px; }
.item { width:600px; padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none; }
a { display:block; width:60PX; line-height:25px;/*24px*/ border-bottom:1px none #808080; font-family:'arial narrow',sans-serif; color:#FFF; padding: 0px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; margin-bottom:0em; }                      
a.item { float:left;/* For horizontal left to right display. */ width:100px;/* For maintaining equal  */ margin-right:0px;/* space between two boxes. */ }                      
a.selected { background:#5B000C; color:white; }

   </style>         
</head>
<body>  
        <div id="navigation">   
            <a class="item" href="#" >HOME</a>
            <a class="item" href="#" >SUITE</a>
            <a class="item" href="#" >TEAM</a>
            <a class="item" href="#" >LOCATION</a>
            <a class="item" href="#" >CONTACT</a>
            <a class="item" href="#" >MAP</a>
        </div> 
         <script>
        var anchorArr=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var prevA="";
        for(var i=0;i<anchorArr.length;i++)
        {
            anchorArr[i].onclick = function(){
                if(prevA!="" && prevA!=this)
                {
                    prevA.className="item";
                }
                this.className="item selected";
                prevA=this;
            }
        }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you reload the page when `href`s are set and therefore it goes back to default styling. You'll need to figure out a way to add `selected` class to appropriate menu item on page load.

...or you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4626582/3454330)