# Adding image and changing background color when switching tab in list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing an application in ios.

on click on each tab in left navigation bar i have to display different data which works fine. The problem i am facing is i have to change the background color of li,text color of anchor tag and add an image(selection arrow) to the li which i click. my html code for left navigation bar is below

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
<li onclick="function1()">
<a>SO SUMMARY </a></li>
<li  onclick="function2()">
<a>ROUTEPLANNING</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function3()"><a>PRODUCT/<br>
PROBLEM<br>
DETAILS</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function4()"><a>KEY DATES</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function5()">
<a>JOB DETAILS</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function6()"><a>LABOUR</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function7()"><a>PARTS</a> 
</li>
<li onclick="function8()"><a>ANALYSIS LOG</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function9()"><a>CLOSURE</a>
</li>
<li onclick="function10()"><a>COLLABRATION</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

please help me with this.

Comment: refer css selectors and pseudo classes for this like :after, :hover, :active etc. also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514344/how-to-highlight-currently-opened-page-link-in-css/26514790#26514790 for ideas as well

Comment: i have tried this   $(.sidebar-nav li).click()

Comment: It's difficult to see what's happening here, with lack of css. But have you tried a rule similar to **li:active{}** etc? If so, could you provide your attempts so we're not suggesting answers that you've already attempted??

Comment: in css i have tried this. .sidebar-nav li a.actve{//styles for selected li} but no luck